# Git config across multiple machines?

Tags: git

If I have an external drive (D:) that I want to put a repo on in addition to the one on my local machine (C:), to copy my git config settings, is it really as simple as copying the file and pasting it into my new git repo, or is there a better way (symlink or otherwise)?

Comment: If the settings are repo-specific then yes, copying will work. If they're meant to be global though, you really shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to be across multiple drives, not multiple machines (as in PCs), correct?

Comment: Huh, interesting! So what if I have an external drive connected to my machine over USB, does that also mean that the --global switch should work?

Comment: Yes, using `--global` stores your config options in a `.gitconfig` file in your home directory. (On Linux: `~/.gitconfig`, on Windows (if I remember correctly): C:\\Users\<YourUsername>\)

Comment: WoW, that's pretty awesome. Thanks for your help, Ajedi32. :)